# I'm getting error running npm run start with parcel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm, parcel

I am using parcel to run my bootstrap 5, I unknowingly tempered with my package.json file, I had to reset my repo to the last commit, after doing that I keep getting a terminal error "undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function" anytime i run  $npm run start, i tried reinstalling the package dependencies, now it doesn't give the error, but whenever i clicked on the local server link it gives an error 404: page not found.

Error message

[image: 1]

Comment: Remove `node_modules` run `npm install` then run `npm run start` and see what happens

Comment: I'm still getting same error

Comment: I have no idea what can be wrong as we don't know how your `package.json` looks like or any other configuration file

Comment: `{
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "default": "reg.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./src/admin.html",
    "prebuild": "npx rimraf build",
    "build": "parcel build admin.html --dist-dir ./dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0"
  }
}
` this is my package,json

Comment: I just discovered that the above error comes whenever i add an href attribute to my anchor tags, this is weird 